# No graphics card Server - Black Screen

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, graphics

I have searched this forum and search engines for answers, and tried many, but no joy. 
I had a corrupt system, Ubuntu 16.04.5 (yes it is server).
The system became corrupt when someone ran a `chmod 777` command for `etc/` folder,
I ran rescue broken system a few times, checked files and so forth, to no avail. I was never able to get it to boot. I just got the black screen and no further. I checked files etc, but still never got past the back screen. 
I ended up without a fix, and I made a backup of the `etc/` directory (as through rescue a broken system I could get command line). I then proceeded to reinstall 16.04.5 
However, on reinstalling I reformatted the HD, and reinstalled, yet when I go to boot up I have black screen. 
There is no graphics card with this server, and in the installation file called syslinux.cfg I amended the file code to read for example:

```
label ubnentry6
menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
kernel /install/vmlinuz
append initrd=/install/initrd.gz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed 
vga=off console=ttyS0,115200n8 –
```

In Grub, I have replaced `Quiet Splash` with `Quiet Splash nomodest`  and `nomodest`   and also tried `text` but again no joy. I did run `sudo update-grub`
Anybody else have any ideas on how to get past this black screen? I imagine it is still looking for a graphics card of some sort, but as said it is a straight server with no graphics as all on it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "ctrl+alt+f1" when you are on the black screen ?

It does not take care of the problem but at least it made it possible to install openssh and use the server remotely without having to ctrl-alt-f1 everytime.